# Azure Synapse Studio - WorkFlow

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am new to Azure Synapse Studio.

I am working with Synapse analytics and Loaded the data from NYTaxi and successfully created Database using a loading user etc.

But once I create a Workspace in Synapse Analytics and then Launched the Azure Synapse Studio.

- I could not see any database
- I wanted to know how to create a Dataset
- I wanted to know how to deal with PowerBI within Studio

Also related to Apache Spart etc I need help

Thanks in Advance
Vijay Perepa

Answer (score 3):

- With *Azure Synapse Analytics (Workspace preview)* deployment no SQL Pool is deployed. You can do this in the Synapse workspace (create new SQL pool), also with sample data.
- A dataset can be created in the data area (tab linked). Main purpose is metadata information (e. g. for Parquet files in your attached Azure Data Lake Store or a SQL Pool table) that can be used in a Data Flow.
- PowerBI: You can link a PowerBI Workspace to Azure Synapse Analytics (Manage - Linked Service). With this you can create PowerBI datasets accessing data in your SQL Pool.

As a good starting point I would recommend the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/overview-what-is). There you also find some usefull [Tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started). Lot' s of samples are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Synapse). Hope this helps.